# PHP variable dont show in echo

Tags: php

Hey im struggeling with a simple task but i cant find the error.

This is my currenct code

```
Global $user_ID;
$user_ID = get_current_user_id();

echo"User number $user_ID is loggedin";
```

Echo returns me "User number 2 is loggedin"

Now i want to add the $user_id to an array

```
$atts['href'] .=  $user_ID. 'abc';
```

The 'href' is set to "https://test.de/"

The echo returns me now: "https://test.de/abc

Why the id is not added?

Comment: So if you want to add `$user_id` to an array, why do you add `$newid`?

Comment: sorry was troubleshooting and didnt changed it back to $user_id

Answer (score 2):

İt happens because you address to the wrong variable. You need to use $user_id variable. Check this out:

```
global $user_ID;
$user_ID = get_current_user_id();


echo"User number $user_ID is loggedin";

$atts['href'] .=  $user_ID . 'abc';
```

Comment: When writing an answer, always include an explanation of what it solves and why. Even if it seems obvious.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson added an explanation

Comment: thanks for that reply. was my fault to post wrong variable. i added the right variable but it still does nothing

Comment: @juliangommer can you post full code from the beginning till the end?